tensorflow 2.16.2 keras 3 can't pass tuple of eager tensors as shape argument for Layer add_weight, but could in tf 2.11
I am updating some code from tensorflow 2.11 to 2.16.2. It is crashing when calling the build() of a class derived from Keras.Layer. The code calls the layer self.add_weight function. That function takes a shape argument.
What it is passing is an tuple of eager tensors for the shape - like
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=9>,)
add_weight eventually gets into this function
> /usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/keras/src/backend/common/variables.py(549)standardize_shape() 
where it does
525 def standardize_shape(shape):
    543     for e in shape:
    549         if not is_int_dtype(type(e)):
    550 

and that function is_int_dtype crashes with
*** ValueError: Invalid dtype: <property object at 0x7f357256a430>


The type of e is a eager tensor, not an actual int. Seems like a subtle change somewhere - I'll see if I can change the code to generate a list of ints, but I would think a list of tensors or eager tensors should be OK for the shape? It kind of seems like a bug. I'm inclined to try tf 2.17.0, but I didn't see anything about this in the release notes.
